# How to display ArrayList in webform

Tags: c#, asp.net, arraylist

Good evening everyone

I have a faults column in a table which holds string type value. Each cell in that column may contain multiple comma separated faults (Ex : CPU not wkg, HDD corrupt etc). My requirement is to read the value of each cell, store each fault in an ArrayList and then print a table such that it displays two columns (faultname, noOftimeItccured). To achieve this I am Sorting the array list and then finding the number occurrence of each fault.
Issue I am facing 
1.  I am not getting the desired result (there might be some issue in the logic)
2.  unable to display result in format of table in webform.
3.   the result should be shown after the grid view whereas its showing above the menubar.

pls guide me in getting the desired result, output or some alternate method to achieve the above issue discussed.

Thanks in advance.

```
        if (ddlSparesInfo.SelectedValue == "Fast Moving Spares")
        {
            lblMessage.Text = "";
            try
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("getFastMovingSpares", DBConn.Conn);
                DBConn.OpenConn();
                using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    ArrayList faults = new ArrayList();
                    while (dr.Read())
                    {
                        string cellValue = dr.GetString(7);
                        string[] splitFaults = cellValue.Split(',');
                        for (int i = 0; i < splitFaults.Length; i++)
                        {
                            faults.Add(splitFaults[i]);
                        }
                    }

                    faults.Sort();
                    int count = 1;
                    for (int i = 1; i < faults.Count; i++)
                    {
                        if (faults[i - 1] == faults[i])
                        {
                            count++;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Response.Write("<table>");
                            Response.Write("<tr>");
                            Response.Write("<td>");
                            Response.Write("<p>" + faults[i] + "<p>");
                            Response.Write("</td>");
                            Response.Write("<td>");
                            Response.Write("<p>" + count + "<p>");
                            Response.Write("</td>");
                            Response.Write("</tr>");
                            Response.Write("</table>");
                            count = 0;
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                throw;
            }
            finally
            {
                DBConn.CloseConn();

            }

        }
    }
```

[Screenshot of Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ev6ZV.png)

[Screenshot of output after making changes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zuO68.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Dictionary<key,value>` to store faults and count of them.

```
 if (ddlSparesInfo.SelectedValue == "Fast Moving Spares")
            {
                lblMessage.Text = "";
                try
                {
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("getFastMovingSpares", DBConn.Conn);
                    DBConn.OpenConn();
                    using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {

                        Dictionary<string, int> faults = new Dictionary<string, int>();
                        while (dr.Read())
                        {
                            string cellValue = dr.GetString(7);
                            string[] splitFaults = cellValue.Split(',');
                            for (int i = 0; i < splitFaults.Length; i++)
                            {
                                string currentFault = splitFaults[i];
                                if (faults.Keys.Any(x => x == currentFault))
                                {
                                    faults[currentFault] += 1;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    faults.Add(currentFault, 1);
                                }
                            }
                        }


                        Response.Write("<table>");
                        foreach (var fault in faults)
                        {

                            Response.Write("<tr>");
                            Response.Write("<td>");
                            Response.Write("<p>" + fault.Key + "<p>");
                            Response.Write("</td>");
                            Response.Write("<td>");
                            Response.Write("<p>" + fault.Value + "<p>");
                            Response.Write("</td>");
                            Response.Write("</tr>");
                        }

                        Response.Write("</table>");
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {

                    throw;
                }
                finally
                {
                    DBConn.CloseConn();

                }

}
```

Comment: Thanks Ahmet I was able to achieve the desired output using Dictionary but still I am unable to figure out how to display the keyvaluepair in a tabular format on webform from c# code or any other alternative.

Comment: After you fill your dictionary, in another loop, iterate for Dictionary items.

Comment: Hi Ahmet I have uploaded the code and the screenshot of webform pls guide me 
1. how can I display the output of dictionary as a table
2. output is shown above the menubar how to avoid this

Comment: Hi Ahmet thanks for reply, the output is still displaying above the Menubar.attached screenshot of the same

Comment: This is another problem dude. Your question is about listing the faults with counts. This is a platform to find answers. Not to make someone to write your application.

Comment: Hi Ahmet I am a beginner in coding and have to learn much from person like u and improve my knowledge. However I had mentioned it in the question that I am facing this issue I am trying to figure out from last few days and I have got stuck. I Was able to solve the first two issue with your help thanks a lot.Got an idea for third issue will post back if it works.

Comment: You have to search about response write issues. Improvement can be achieved by search, read and exercise. Good luck